# Montar estrutura com dados hexadecimais

Tags: javascript, node.js

Fala pessoal tudo bem ? recebo de um socket um buffer de 116 bytes em hexadecimal esses bytes tem uma estrutura, por exemplo:

Partindo do inicio:

```
2 bytes = 1ª variável
1 byte  = 2ª variável
1 byte  = 3ª variável
2 bytes = 4ª variável
2 bytes = 5ª variável
4 bytes = 6ª variável
```

E assim vai até completar toda sua estrutura, como posso montar isso em javascript para usar no node ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VOcê não diz que tipos de dados serão as variáveis - assumindo que são sempre inteiros sem sinal, essa resposta funciona -  a propósito, não existem "dados em hexadecimal" - existem dados que são sequências de bytes - você ter eles transformados numa string em que são representados como uma sequência de números hexadecimais de 2 dígitos. As funções abaixo assumem que sua string, ao contrário, contenha os próprios bytes como "codepoints" unicode - se de sua string tiver de fato os dados em hexadecimal, você vai precisar converter esses números em hexa para "números" de verdade antes - uma vez tendo uma sequência de números de 0 a 255, as funções são quase as mesmas:

Se você não precisar/não quiser os nomes das variáveis, e se os seus dados estiverem numa string e forem ["big endian"](https://arqufs2008.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/little-endian-vs-big-endian/), esta função resolve o problema:

```
function extract_data(spec, stream) {
    var result = new Array;
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < spec.length; i++) {
        var size = spec[i];
        var item = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            item <<= 8;
            item += stream.codePointAt(index);
            index++;
        }
        result.push(item)
    }
    return result
}
```

Onde "spec" é justamente  a descrição de quantos bytes tem cada variável 
(de novo, assumindo que sejam todos inteiros positivos, com larguras variáveis de bytes) - no seu exemplo, spec seria `[2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4]`.
Se os dados forem little-endian, você vai precisar desta variante:

```
function extract_data(spec, stream) {
    var result = new Array;
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < spec.length; i++) {
        var size = spec[i];
        var item = 0;
        for (var j = size - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            item <<= 8;
            item += stream.codePointAt(index + j);
        }
        index += size;
        result.push(item)
    }
    return result
}
```

(o operador `y <<= X` faz um shift de X dígitos binários no conteúdo do número y - o mesmo que multiplicar o número por 2^8  (256): isso é quantas vezes um byte mais significativo é maior que outro ao compor números inteiros no computador).